# Почему выдает ошибку скомпилированого файла, когда ввожу команду на скачивание файла

Tags: python, компиляция

Почему выдает когда дохожу до команды закачки файлов из библиотеки wget и requests вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'queue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
    __import__(name + "__init__")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 21, in <module>
    scriptModule = __import__(moduleName)
  File "PyTake.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "c:\PyTake\ptCallRequestsTroune.py", line 20, in __callRequestsMode__
    ptRequestsTroune.__requestsMode__()
  File "c:\PyTake\ptRequestsTroune.py", line 33, in __requestsMode__
    ptDefaultCommandsTroune.__procStandartHide__()
  File "c:\PyTake\ptDefaultCommandsTroune.py", line 116, in __procStandartHide__
    ptRootTroune.__rootMode__()
  File "c:\PyTake\ptRootTroune.py", line 105, in __rootMode__
    getSurge.__surgeTake__()
  File "c:\PyTake\getSurge.py", line 22, in __surgeTake__
    import requests
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'queue'
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Что у вас `import queue; print(queue.__file__)` показывает. Имеет смысл явно упомянуть что вы cx_Freeze используете.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена методом импорта модуля из multiproccessing импортировали модуль queue!

Comment: Есть `multiprocessing.queues` модуль, который отличается от queue модуля. Вы не можете из multiprocessing импортировать queue модуль.

Comment: @jfs могу, я всё могу

Comment: Покажите как вы импортируете (код)

Comment: @jfs Взяв Через def __static__(): #from multiprocessing import Queue

Comment: `multiprocessing.Queue` это ~класс, а не модуль.  Я не вижу каким боком это исправляет `ImportError` из вопроса внутри `requests/urllib3/six` (`ImportError: No module named 'queue'`).

Comment: @jfs Если честно я не знаю, у меня каким то боком работает .-.

Comment: возвращается ли `ImportError`, если вы уберёте *одну* строчку: `from multiprocessing import Queue` в вашем коде? Или другая ошибка возникает?

Comment: @jfs Нет, просто py файлом все работает нормально, но вот когда компилирую файл и запускаю возникает ошибка. Поэтому  я и добавил эту строку, потому что он не находи Queue.  Вот ответ на вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432426/importerror-no-module-named-queue

Comment: Создавали ли вы файл с именем: `queue.py`? (если  создали, то переименуйте или внутрь пакета спрячьте). [В ссылке, которую вы привели](https://goo.gl/dKVR6A), у автора была проблема, что он свой файл `queue.py` назвал (что конфликтует со стандартным модулем).  Это так называемый [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap). Код пытался выполнить: `from queue import LifoQueue, ...` (ожидая стандартный модуль) и так как свой нестандартный `queue.py` не содержал `LifoQueue`, ...

Comment: ...[продолжение] то это приводило к ImportError, а так как код написан для поддержки как Питона 2 так и 3, то после этого `from Queue import LifoQueue` там пробуется (код думает, что если нет `queue.LifoQueue`, то это не Питон 3, а Питон 2, где существует `Queue.LifoQueue` (стандартный модуль был переименован при переходе с Питона 2 на Питон 3: Queue -> queue). Ответ с плюсами там (`from multiprocessing import Queue`) не имеет никакого отношения к действительной проблеме автора вопроса—ни-ка-ко-го.

Comment: если вы уберёте *одну* строчку: `from multiprocessing import Queue` из вашего кода и скомпилируете файл и запустите его, то возникает ли ImportError (та же ошибка что и в вопросе) или другая ошибка возникает?